# XmlPullParser xpp.getName() returning null

Tags: java, android, performance, xml-parsing

I have read through most of the errors that seem to be the same but I am not seeing it.  my code below is suppose to use only the items I have requested, but I get nothing.  The line at the bottom I have commented out will fill myXML, but my if code is ignored. I used the name field below thinking I could set it like a flag, but that didn't work.  I have tried xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("summary"), with no luck either.  My XML comes from here http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&sensor=false

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name = xpp.getName();
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                    System.out.println("Start document");
                    name = xpp.getName();
                } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    System.out.println("Start tag " + xpp.getName());
                    name = xpp.getName();
                } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    System.out.println("End tag " + xpp.getName());
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                    name = xpp.getName();
                {
                    System.out.println("Text " + xpp.getText());
                    if (name == "summary") { myXML = myXML + xpp.getText() + "\n"; }
                    if (name == "duration") { myXML = myXML + "Duration:" + " "; }
                    if (name == "distance") { myXML = myXML + "Distance:" + " "; }
                    if (name == "value") { myXML = myXML + xpp.getText() + " "; }
                    if (name == "text") { myXML = myXML + xpp.getText() + "\n"; }
                    if (name == "html_instructions") { myXML = myXML + xpp.getText() + "\n"; }
                    if (name == "maneuver") { myXML = myXML + xpp.getText() + "\n"; }

                    //myXML = myXML + xpp.getText() + "\n";

                }
                try {
                    eventType = xpp.next();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("End document");


            return myXML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I had painstakingly figured out is that my checks for the start Tags needed to be in the if else for the start tags. at that point I was able to move forward.